# Low Pass filter using Parrallel components

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, filter, low-pass, digital-filter

I have a PCB design that I need to add a low pass filter. However I can only add components in parallel. It is going to be very difficult to cut the tracks or add components in series. Is there any way to create the low pass filter or similar filter ? The frequency of noise I have to reduce is between approx. 5KHz to 45KHz

I have to add a filter to the INA826A outputs as shown below

[image]

Comment: Show us some details about your circuit inputs. If it simply is a trace going to some IC input, it will be pretty hard implementing a filter without cutting the trace. If there already is some sort of input resistance as a dedicated part like a resistor, then that might be something to work with.

Comment: Capacitor in parallel?

Comment: What exactly is driving those inputs? If it's low impedance, or active circuitry that becomes unstable under a capacitive load, you will need to insert series elements.

Comment: It's not going to happen.

Comment: you would need a balanced filter to avoid corrupting the signal to the amplifiers (one cap between the input and one cap toward ground) but to be stable it needs also some kind of resistive load. Need to know what's attached to IN23 and so on. Otherwise you'll waste the money for the precision amplifiers

Comment: Forgot to say: you have to filter the *inputs* of the amplifiers since otherwise you risk noise to be rectified in… strange ways. I didn't check the BW of that INA but it could have issues at 40kHz

Comment: I have updated the schematic ! We think that a lot of the noise is coming from the INA826 - thus we have been recommended to try to put a filter on the outputs and see if it helps.....

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on your impedance to ground at this spot. If it's mostly resistive, you can just add a capacitor to ground. Depending on your circuit & signals you may have to limit the current through this capacitor for very high frequencies.

Comment: My frequencies are currently less than 45KHz - is this low enough to the current limit you suggested ? How do I figure out the value of the capacitor ?

Comment: His impedence at the ina output is that of the driving stage, he can't put a capacitor without overloading it. It needs a series resistor. Also usually noise need to be removed *before* the inamp

Comment: So its there's no way to get this low pass filter without adding a series resistor ?